# In-app purchase receipt verification with RMStore/AppReceiptVerificator

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt

I am building an iOS app  which contains in-app purchase for IAP receipt verification I am trying to use  `Pod 'RMStore/AppReceiptVerificator'` but I am unable to install through pods.

Is there any other library which does the same work or how can we use `RMStoreAppReceiptVerificator`?

This library trying to install OpenSsl and getting this error

> cp: file.tgz: No such file or directory

How do I solve this issue while installing this library?

Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance !!